# Error Initializing R web with localhost and java 8

Tags: java, r

I am getting the following error when running this code
   **Error**

```
   Starting H2O JVM and connecting: ............................................................ 
[1] "localhost"
[1] 54321
[1] TRUE
[1] -1
[1] "Failed to connect to localhost port 54321: Connection refused"
[1] 127
Error in h2o.init() : H2O failed to start, stopping execution.
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'curl 'http://localhost:54321'' had status 127 
> 

library('h2o')
sys.setenv('C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath')
localH2O = h2o.init()
```

unable to see the visualization page of h2o

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392394/error-with-h2o-in-r-cant-connect-to-local-host

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with H2O in R - can't connect to local host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392394/error-with-h2o-in-r-cant-connect-to-local-host)